# C# - Can't get buttons to react to index of element in list

Tags: c#, list, button

I have a picturebox in my system that displays a thumbnail image from a `List<Bitmap>` called `images`. There is a button on either side of the picturebox that allows the user to move to the previous or next image. What I would like to happen is that when the picturebox is on the first image of the List, then the 'previous' button is disabled, and same for the last image and the 'next' button. At any other time, the user should be able to scroll in either direction. 
I have written a function called `checkFirstLast()` to try and implement this, and am testing it with only two elements in the `images` List. The function is shown below, and is called every time the image on the picturebox is changed:

```
    //Bitmap passed in represents image currently displayed on picbox
    public void checkFirstLast(Bitmap displayImage)
    {
        if (displayImage == images.First())
        {
            //cant go back
            //set prev button as inactive
            btnPrevImage.Enabled = false;
            btnPrevImage.BackColor = INACTIVECOLOUR;

            //can go forward
            //set next button as active
            btnNextImage.Enabled = true;
            btnNextImage.BackColor = ACTIVECOLOUR;
        }
        else if (displayImage == images.Last())
        {
            //can go back
            //set prev button as active
            btnPrevImage.Enabled = true;
            btnPrevImage.BackColor = ACTIVECOLOUR;

            //cant go forward
            //set next button as inactive
            btnNextImage.Enabled = false;
            btnNextImage.BackColor = INACTIVECOLOUR;
        }
        else
        {
            //can go back
            //set prev button as active
            btnPrevImage.Enabled = true;
            btnPrevImage.BackColor = ACTIVECOLOUR;

            //can go forward
            //set next button as active
            btnNextImage.Enabled = true;
            btnNextImage.BackColor = ACTIVECOLOUR;
        }
    }
```

When the application loads, it loads to the first element in the `images`, and the `checkFirstLast()` function is run. This means that at this point, the 'previous' button is disabled while the 'next' button is enabled. However, when the 'next' button is clicked (`checkFirstLast()` run again) and the picturebox shows the second (last) element in `images`, neither button changes enabled state as it should.
This means that the system becomes stuck on the last element in the List and can go neither backwards (button not enabled), nor forwards (no more images, although button stays enabled).

I don't really understand what could be going wrong, surely if the function operates as expected first time around then it can't just not work when called again?
Not sure where to go from here, any advice or a point in the direction of where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Mark

Comment: you might need to refresh your gui (nudge it :))... not sure what you're running where, but it might help. alse, why not have both enabled, if first, disable back, if last disable forward, instead of repeating it in each if block ?

Comment: It is a winform application?? call Refresh method for buttons

Comment: I don't think it's a refresh problem. @marcuthh: are you sure the displayImage == images.First()? I mean, can they be different (clone) in memory?

Comment: @marcuthh FYI: I think your method will produce an incorrect result if there is only one image. That method cannot correctly handle an image being both first _and_ last.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, I have realised that the function that called the next image was returning it as an individual Bitmap and therefore any statement that compared it to .first() or .last() was recognising it but was still using the index of the prior image which had not been updated. This has been corrected now, but thankyou for your input :)